# Sort numerically and alphabetically in Python

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a pandas series, 50K rows and two columns. I need to sort the "syn" column first numerically and then alphabetically.

| name | syn |
| --- | --- |
| name1 | 1616TD, K25, PP785, 70-07200 |
| name2 | WTR-098, 0616TD, K25, PP785, 70-07200 |
| name50 | ..... |

So that I get the below output: extra sorted column

| name | syn | sorted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | 1616TD, K25, PP785, 70-07200 | 1616TD, 70-07200, K25, PP785 |
| name2 | WTR-098, 0616TD, K25, PP785, 70-07200 | 0616TD, 70-07200, K25, PP785, WTR-098 |
| name50 | ........ |  |

The "syn" column is string, may contain hyphens, and spaces after commas. I have shared how the first two rows look like.

Comment: Do you want to sort the values inside of the column `syn`, or the dataframe according the column `syn`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'name':['name1', 'name2'], 
     'syn':[['1616TD', 'K25', 'PP785', '70-07200'], ['WTR-098', '0616TD', 'K25', 'PP785', '70-07200']]
    }
)
df.syn = df.syn.apply(lambda x: sorted(x))
print(df)
```

Result:

```
    name                                      syn
0  name1           [1616TD, 70-07200, K25, PP785]
1  name2  [0616TD, 70-07200, K25, PP785, WTR-098]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort inside the column `syn` try this:

```
data["syn"].apply(lambda x:",".join(sorted(list(map(lambda y:y.strip(),x.split(","))))))
```